# How to set charset header in Django 1.11

Tags: django, django-views, django-1.1

we are using Django1.11 and we are having some problems because our header `Content-Type` does not contain the `charset` part set to UTF-8. Something like this:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

I want to fix that for all endpoints, so I have thought to include a middleware to run after all midlewares have been run. The problem is that I do not know if that's possible. Any ideas? Or alternative solutions?

Comment: You're using standard views to output json, without django-rest-framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom middleware like this:

```py
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin


class AllIsJsonMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        response['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        return response
```

But I don't recommend this. This converts all responses to JSON. Best use a framework like https://www.django-rest-framework.org/.

However, can use a standard view respone...

```py
return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json; charset=UTF-8')
```

... or a custom decorator:

```py
from functools import wraps

def json_response(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = function(request, *args, **kwargs)
        response['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        return response
    return wrap

@json_response
def my_view(request):
    # ....
```

Comment: This         response['charset'] = 'UTF-8' does not set the charset on the Content-Type. I'm still seeing application/json only.

Comment: Yes. is `response['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'`